# Django forms.ModelForm, Pylint, and new/old style classes

Tags: python, django, pylint

I have a Django 1.5 form that looks like this (simplified):

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
        )
        model = Bid

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BidForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        something()
```

When I run Pylint on this, I get a this error:

```
E1002:<line,row>:BidForm.__init__: Use of super on an old style class
```

I assume this means the Django's forms.ModelForm is an old-style class and per the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) my call to super is not happening and is therefore extraneous.  Is this true?  Can I just delete the super call without effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error/warning has nothing to do with the ModelForm class and has to do with:

```
    class Meta:
        fields = ()
        model = Bid
```

You just need to suppress the warning:

```
    class Meta:  # pylint: disable=C1001
        fields = ()
        model = Bid
```

Comment: Or you can just use the new-style class instead, i.e. `class Meta(object):`, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2007514/1226722).

Answer (score 9):

No. Pylint, great though it is, is far from infallible, and in this case has just got it wrong. ModelForm is a new style class and the super is needed.

Comment: Thanks -- I thought that ModelForm was new-style and figured I was just missing something.  I wish Pylint had a way to submit issues, but I can't seem to find a way to do so...

Comment: @Erik the manpage has a `BUGS` section that directs you to `python-projects@lists.logilab.org`.

Comment: Pylint bug reports are now maintained on Bitbucket. I have opened an issue for this one: https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue/24/e1002-message-for-djangoformsmodelform